# Magento 2: how do I remove language selection

Tags: frontend, language

Hi on my front page there is a dropdown menu that allows me to select different languages.  Is there way I can remove this dropdown menu? thank!

Answer (score 9):

just add:

```
<referenceBlock name="store_language" remove="true"/>
```

in:

> /app/design/frontend/***YourPackage***/***YourTheme***/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Comment: thank you that worked great! Have been searching and fiddling for over an hour.

Comment: No problem man, this will work for all what you need remove from page...
and don't forget for "move" action, eg.
*<move element="store_language" destination="footer" after="-" />*